# How do I return a DataFrame for each row in the DataFrame and concatenate the result into a DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I have

```
df = DataFrame(a = 1:3, d = 4:6)

fn(val) = DataFrame(d = [val, val])
```

what I want to do is to apply a function `fn` to each row of the data frame and return a dataframe that contains the results row-combined in a DataFrame.

I know I can do `vcat` but is there a more efficient way?

E.g. this is possible

```
reduce(vcat, [fn(row.d) for row in eachrow(df)])
```

or

```
mapreduce(row -> fn(row.d), vcat, eachrow(df))
```

Or more generally, if I want to apply a function to each row and the function returns a `DataFrame` as output. What's the most efficient way to have the results `vcat` in a table?

Comment: `vcat` is efficient if you insist that `fn` should return a `DataFrame` (i.e. no other method can be expected to be faster as `reduce` of `vcat` is optimized exactly to perform this operation maximally efficiently). On the other hand `mapreduce` will not be efficient as it is not optimized.

Comment: whether `fn` return a dataframe is not important. I just want the final output to be a dataframe contain all the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask about performance all details matter. In your case the fastest thing to do is (all timings are after compilation; I have increased the size of the data frame to make the results easier to compare):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:3+10^6, d = 4:6+10^6);

julia> @time reduce(vcat, [fn(row.d) for row in eachrow(df)]);
  4.897246 seconds (33.06 M allocations: 2.143 GiB, 36.03% gc time, 1.11% compilation time)

julia> @time DataFrame(d=repeat(df.d, inner=2), copycols=false);
  0.006518 seconds (26 allocations: 15.261 MiB)
```

Now, let me turn to a relatively fast pattern that is easy to remember and general:

```
julia> fn2(x) = [x, x]; # this is already inefficient, as it creates a vector per row

julia> @time flatten(select(df, :d => ByRow(fn2) => :d), :d);
  0.135725 seconds (1.00 M allocations: 144.971 MiB)

julia> fn3(x) = (x, x); # better use e.g. a tuple as a temporary container

julia> @time flatten(select(df, :d => ByRow(fn3) => :d), :d);
  0.027856 seconds (177 allocations: 53.418 MiB)
```

Still this is an slower than the most efficient solution for your case which uses `repeat`.

Now to see that the patterns are relatively efficient compare them with the same approach using just Julia Base (of course there is some overhead above as the `DataFrame` objects need to be created and manipulated):

```
julia> @time collect(Iterators.flatten(fn2.(df.d)));
  0.096385 seconds (1.00 M allocations: 116.183 MiB, 17.88% gc time)

julia> @time collect(Iterators.flatten(fn3.(df.d)));
  0.014566 seconds (7 allocations: 30.518 MiB)
```